# How to not reuse UITableViewCell and keep cells in memory after they disappear from the view?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

I have a "not so big" dynamic tableView with a number of rows that can vary between 10 and 20.

I used Storyboard and created 4 different cell prototypes which all have their own identifier. Most of these cells have `UITextFields` in them and the user will enter information such as e-mail adresses etc...

I use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` in `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` to create my cells.

---

However whenever I scroll my tableView I can see that the appearing cells get the data from upper cells, because cells that disappear are enqueued for reuse.

Given the fact that I have a limited number of cells, I would like to get rid of the reusing feature and just have my set of cells with their own data inside. When I scroll down I see cells that correspond to the lower cells, and when I go back up I see again my upper cells.

How can I do that?
and how can I then create a cell that corresponds to a prototype from the storyboard without using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` ?

---

I have already searched among similar question here in StackOverflow and tried to keep an array of my cells and just return the correct element if it already exists from `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` but nothing worked so far

Comment: `but nothing worked so far` post what you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

You are overthinking this a bit. If you think about what `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` does, it just grabs a cell that it finds with that specific identifier. If you want every row to have it's own unique cell that is not used by any other row, just give each row it's own identifier. The simplest way would be to just to stringify the indexPath row, or both the row+section if you have multiple sections.

Something like this should do it:

```
let cellIdentifier = String(indexPath.section) + "-" + String(indexPath.row)
```

Comment: Yes but l need the content styling set in the storyboard and it comes from the identifier.

Comment: Ah, well then the answer is, you probably can't do what you're trying. You should just set up the cells to work correctly when they are reused like they normally would be and then you won't have any problems. Do you need help with that?

Comment: Finally ended up with keeping a copy of my data and putting it back on the cells when recreated. I was lazy to do so and hoping to see if there was a workaround, but at last I have finally something that works :)

Comment: That's ultimately the best solution, you don't want to depend on table cells to hold important data. Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

In these cases I will typically create what would be the content of the table view cell in its own view controller or custom view, something like "SignupFormViewController", and store that as a property on the view controller that is managing your table view.  In your case this could also be multiple view controllers of this type in several properties or an array.  Then dequeue your cells as normal but treat them as dumb containers to which the view controllers' views are added as subviews.  Then you'll just to have tie up all the loose ends—removing the view from the cell when the cell dequeued, not adding a view if the identical view is already a child of the cell, constraints to match cell size, etc.